# chunked file upload with blueimp and oneuploaderbundle

Tags: symfony, jquery-file-upload, oneupuploaderbundle

I am trying to upload big files using Symfony (with [OneUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle)) and [Jquery File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).
It looks like my program does only one chunk (I can see the chunk in the filesystem) and then fail with a message :

"*Error: Call to a member function getBasename() on a non-object*".

My code looks like this :

**JS**

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    formData: {prestation: prestation},
    acceptFileTypes:  /(zip)|(rar)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 100000000,
    maxChunkSize:  3000000, 
});
```

**PHP**

I do not know what to do to be honest, I believe I have to return something so that the second chunk can run but I don't know what.
I have started checking the events, especially the PostChunkUploadEvent with no luck...

```
//An upload Listener
 public function onChunkUpload(PostChunkUploadEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $chunk = $event->getChunk();
}
```

I saw also that Jquery File-upload provides a PHP upload handler [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php) but not sure how to use it with OneUploaderBundle.

Im a bit lost, any Help ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer.

The problem was coming from my filesystem. Using Gaufrette solved things...